# Unable to extract content from bootstrap-wyswyg editor

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I am using [Bootstrap Wysiwyg Editor](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/).I wrote following code

```
<form method="post" action="">
<div id="editor" name="content"><p>Write here...</p></div>
<input style="" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['content'])) {
$content = $_POST['content'];
echo $content;
}
?>
```

But it echos nothing. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a DIV the way you expect textareas to be used. HTML form elements do not get DIV content automatically posted. You need to create a hidden element eg

```
<input type="hidden" name="content" id="form-content">
```

and create a javascript event handler for your form or submit button that will prepopulate the hidden field based on the content, eg

```
$('input[name=submit]').click(function () {
   $('#form-content').val($('#editor').html())
});
```